# Magento 1x Sales Order Grid Source

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml

Using magento 1.x I have changed the source of my sales_order grid form `sales/order_grid_collection` to `sales/order_grid_collection`

```
protected function _getCollectionClass() {
        return 'sales/order_collection';
}
```

This works aside form the Bill and Ship to Name fields which are empty. I cann't see why this would be the case. Any ideas why I should be missing these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **sales/order_grid_collection** collection load data from **sales_flat_order_grid** table
2. **sales/order_collection** collection load data from **sales_flat_order** table. This table has no Bill and Ship to Name fields.

That's why missing.

Comment: I see yes - the data I am missing is not stored in the sales_flat_order table, this is the role and purpose of sales_flat_order_grid I guess.